# How to view email's source?

Tags: pantheon-mail

I'm trying to ween myself from "thick" apps like Thunderbird.

Playing with the default mail program (on Juno) - does it not have a way to show the message raw source?

Maybe there is a different email app I should look at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[image: View mail source]

It is quite easy: open the email you want to see the source of, and in the upper right corner click on the three vertical dots -> View Source. It will open Code with the email's source loaded.

Comment: Ha! Thanks. It was obviously too obvious for me to find that. :)

Comment: Glad to help! Please mark the question as answered when you get the chance. Thank you.